# array_keys error from PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_YamlDataSet

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, phpunit, yaml

Trying to load a phpunit dataset using:

```
public function getDataSet()
{
    return new PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_YamlDataSet("/path/file.yml");
}
```

I get

> array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given

on the command line.

I can't tell if the error is because `PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_YamlDataSet::addYamlFile()` doesn't like the input, or if the constructor is returning something that `PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase` doesn't like.

The YAML file was created using phpMyAdmin's YAML export feature. Anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct export from phpMyAdmin does not match the requirements in phpunit.
Take a look at the official documentation:

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html

And now take a look at the file generated by phpMyAdmin. It differs. In phpMyAdmin all table names are just comments.

You have to reformat your file to be usable by phpunit.